# Spring AOP count number of times a particular method is called from another

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have an Interface with the method `rangeQuery()` which I am trying to profile across all subtypes, using Spring AOP.  In particular, for any call to `rangeQuery()` I'd like to know how many times it calls another method `distance()` on a field from its body.

I know that I could write a method that counts all calls to distance as follows:

```
@Before("execution(* *.distance(..))") 
public void count(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    count++
}
```

However, that would not capture which `rangeQuery()` call called it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with AOP, but take a look at http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html , maybe getTarget() or getThis() might be keys to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last resort, in the `@Before` advice above, you can make use of `Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()` and see if the caller is `rangeQuery`.

However, you should find some fixed "pattern" to look for in the stack trace and not just check the Nth position to see if it's the method you're looking for. For example, a sequence of methods that you know should be on the stack at that time in some given order but allowing any other intermediate stack elements to occur. Otherwise, any change in your code would make the advice stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@Before`, you probably have to use `@Around` that allows you to use `ProceedingJoinPoint` to get the source location.

```
 @Around(" ..... ")
  public void test(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    SourceLocation sl = pjp.getSourceLocation();
    System.out.println(sl.getFileName());
    System.out.println(sl.getLine());
    System.out.println(sl.getWithinType());

    // allow through
    pjp.proceed();
  }
```

In you case, it sounds like you might need `call` instead of `execution` but it seems like `call` is not supported in Spring AOP:-

> Other pointcut types
>
> The full AspectJ pointcut language
>   supports additional pointcut
>   designators that are not supported in
>   Spring. These are: call,
>   initialization, preinitialization,
>   staticinitialization, get, set,
>   handler, adviceexecution, withincode,
>   cflow, cflowbelow, if, @this, and
>   @withincode. Use of these pointcut
>   designators in pointcut expressions
>   interpreted by Spring AOP will result
>   in an IllegalArgumentException being
>   thrown.

Comment: getFileName() and getLine() both throw unsupportedOperationException unfortunately

Comment: You might want to use full AspectJ instead of Spring AOP that Spring AOP is pretty vanilla. See section 6.8.4.1 at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html to get you some ideas.

Comment: If you already have `JoinPoint` in your `count()`, perhaps you can do `Class clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass(); String name = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();` to do what you want.